# Boxplots for mutiple columns of dataframe splitted by class

Tags: pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a [dataset](https://github.com/SystemsLab-Sapienza/pump-and-dump-dataset/tree/master/labeled_features) that looks like this:

| Feature A | Feature B | Feature C | labels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.4 | 0 |
| 0.2 | 0.7 | 0.1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Now I want to look into the distribution of the features for the classes. The features are scaled between 0-1 and are divided into two classes (labels 0 or 1).
What I want to do is draw two boxplots for each feature column, one boxplot being the distribution for class 0 and the other for class 1.
All boxplots should be drawn into one figure.

This means in the end I have a figure shwoing six boxplots (FeatureA class1, featureA class0, featureB class1, ...)

This is what I currently am doing:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(14,20)})
sns.boxplot(x="variable", y="value", data=pd.melt(df_here), palette = 'Set2')

plt.show()
```

And I a getting results that look like this:

[image]

How could I split the plots for each feature into two concerning on which class the data belongs to? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a "hue" parameter for the label. Check an example in the seaborn boxplot documentation: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html